# How to overlap items in a ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to recreate the tab effect that the Safari app has on IOS where the tabs are stacked on each other in the tab view and you can scroll through them.

Screenshot of the app using stacks

[image: Screenshot of the app using stacks]

I've successfully achieved this effect however I'm using a SingleChildScrollView and a Stack widget. The problem is this struggles to maintain 30fps.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double containerHeight = widget.workout.length * _cardSpacing + _cardHeight - _cardSpacing;

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      key: PageStorageKey<String>(widget.keyString),
      controller: _scrollController,
      child: Container(
        height: containerHeight,
        child: Stack(
          children: List<Widget>.generate(
            widget.workout.length,
            (int index) => ExerciseCard(
              scrollController: _scrollController,
              topPosition: index * _cardSpacing,
              exercise: widget.workout[index],
              cardSpacing: _cardSpacing,
              cardHeight: _cardHeight,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The rotation and perspective of each card is independent of the others and depends on the cards position on the screen and the offset of the scroll controller. I've tried turning off the transform and I still get bad performance so I think the issue must be that its a SingleChildScrolView and not a ListView. I've tried looking into CustomScrollView and Flow but I've had little success. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
Peters-MacBook-Pro:maxes pcrady$ flutter doctor 
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.13.6, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale en)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Hi @pcrady , were you able to implement this